# File being matched first instead of .htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Whenever I have a file in my webserver and rewrite rule for the same path in my `.htaccess`, the rule is ignored and the file is automatically served.

I have only one file  in the `public_html` of my webserver - `test.php` as follows:

```
<?php
echo "hello ".$_GET['action']
?>
```

Initially my `.htaccess` is empty and so visiting `http://<domain-name>/test.php?action=world` echoes `hello world` as expected. Also my webhost is so configured that visiting `/test?action=world` (with empty `.htaccess`) also echoes hello world.

Now I add the following `.htaccess` in `public_html`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(\w+)$ test.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
```

I expect that visiting `/test/world` will echo `hello world`, but that does not happen! I get only `hello` in the response. Now my initially thought is that `mod_rewrite` is not enabled, so to test that I change the `.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^testmod/(\w+)$ test.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now to my surprise visiting `/testmod/world` actually echoes `hello world`! This shows that `mod_rewrite` is indeed available, and confirms that the rewrite rule is ignored when a file actually exists for the requested url.

My mental model is that Apache goes through the rules in the `.htaccess`, and for any rewrite rule matching the requested rule, Apache internally redirects to path specified in the rule. But that does happen here. It looks like first it checks if there exists any file for the requested url, and if not present, then look at the rewrite rules. Or something entirely else is happening here, maybe because of my webhost's configuration? (FYI, I'm using [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.in/) as my webhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(\w+)$ test.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Cool that works! I also understand that Bluehost is enabling `MultiViews` (since that's not the default behaviour) and that takes precedence over the rewrite rules. This explains the behaviour mentioned in the question. Also after disabling that I confirmed that rewrite rules take precedence over files present.